# How to send Form1 value to other cs

Tags: c#

I know how to send value Form1 to Form2 like and it works fine;

FORM1;

```
        public static string sirket = "";
        public static string personeladı = "";
        public static string desc = "";
        public static string toplampay = "";

        private void prew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<ListViewItem> myList = new List<ListViewItem>();

            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in this.listView1.Items)
            {
                myList.Add(lvi);
            }

            sirket = companyname.Text;
            personeladı = personelcombo.Text;
            desc = paydesc.Text;
            toplampay = totalpay.Text;

            Form2 frm2 = new Form2(listView1);
            frm2.Show();

        }
```

FORM2 ;

```
        string com = Form1.sirket;
        string pers = Form1.personeladı; 
        string descrip = Form1.desc;
        string toppay = Form1.toplampay;
```

My question is I have a form name `Form1`(it is a form) and I wrote `Listviewprint.cs`(not Form).I want to send value Form1 to Listviewprint.cs but when I try to use like above it give me error ;

```
The name 'Form1' does not exist in the current context.
```

How can I send values Form1 to Listviewprint.cs 
[image]

Comment: Where do you instantiate a `ListViewPrint`? In `Form1` or `Form2`?

Comment: depends whats in Listviewprint.cs! hopefully theres a class, and and somewhere in your code you create an instance of it.. just because its not a form doesnt mean you cant pass things to it, but you have to have some variable/method to call to send data between the two

Comment: My listviewprint is under Form1

Comment: @BugFinder could please help me to do that?

Comment: @DjSucuk Id love to but you havent provided enough info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like on form1, you should define it as public on form2 and use it wherever you want to synchronize it. For example  `Textbox1.text = sirket;`

```
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog= ***;Integrated Security=True; Persist Security Info=False");

public static string sirket = "";
public static string personeladı = "";
public static string desc = "";
public static string toplampay = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% clear for me what you really would like to do, but I think this will help you. Comment something if it's not clear for you.

Sou you have the `Form1` class, and you declare your `ListViewPrint` in it. After that you can set it's **public properties** in `Form1`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        private ListViewPrint _mylistviewPrint;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _mylistviewPrint = new _mylistviewPrint(/*or with your parameters*/);
        }

        public void DoSomethingInForm1()
        {
            _mylistviewPrint.SomeVariable = 52;
        }

}

public class ListViewPrint
{
    private int _somevariable;
    public int SomeVariable
    {
        get
        {
            return _somevariable;
        }
        set
        {
            _somevariable = value;
        }
    }

    private string _othervariable;
    /// like the above

}
```

Comment: My listviewprinter.cs is not in Form1 I uploaded my solution explorer

Comment: So where is your ListViewPrinter object?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot in my question

Comment: You have to instantiate ( ListViewPrint myLViewPrint = new ListViewPrint()) somewhere. Where do you do a new object of ListViewPrint?