# How to get textboxt's text from another class c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form `main` and it include a textbox `companyname`and other form name is `Form1` and a class `ListViewPrinter.cs` under `Form1.cs`.I just want to get `companyname` value from `ListViewPrinter.cs`. I tried to do

```
TextBox com = Application.OpenForms["main"].Controls["companyname"] as TextBox;
```

but it gives me `NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code`.How can I get `companyname`
[image]

Comment: `and a class ListViewPrinter.cs under Form1.cs`. What does that even mean?

Comment: I will add some screenshot sorry for my english

Comment: Bro, you've alrdy asked something, I tried to help, but u left the question with no answer. That's not okey.
What about this question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532806/how-to-send-form1-value-to-other-cs/51533052#51533052

Comment: I tried your solution but it's not fix it :( but I gave you upvote :)

Comment: I'd really like to help you, I see what u try to achieve and the way you try it. 
My best advice, do 1-2 Microsoft WinForms tutorials and you will get that correct logic, how to build WinForms applications even with multiple forms.
I think it's unnecessary to answer these very simple questions now, you have to learn the very basics first. Just read and code as much as you can and you will be pro!

Comment: Winforms is pretty relentlessly OOPy, if you don't understand it well enough then you are going to suffer badly.  You get started on that learning curve by relentlessly deleting `static` from your code.  Whatever is in ListViewPrinter.cs no doubt needs a constructor so you can pass the data that it needs to work with.  Push instead of pull.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either make the class `ListViewPrinter` static or create an instance of it. Google for these two terms to get an idea.

Comment: my ListViewPrinter class prints my listview so I need to add company name in this class  from main form

Comment: change definition of ListViewPrinter to static ListViewPrinter.

Comment: it's not fix it :(

Comment: Static class 'BrightIdeasSoftware.ListViewPrinter' cannot derive from type 'BrightIdeasSoftware.ListViewPrinterBase'. Static classes must derive from object.

Comment: I see. in that case you need to create an instance of that class instead of making it static

Answer (score -1):

You may declare **main** form as static and get the value as you will get it from main.

```
public static main main_ = new main();

....

string txtValue = main_.companyname;
```